# use C# connector to insert Chinese into TDengine 2.4.0.16 but got Illegal byte sequence

Tags: c#, tdengine

use `TDengine.Query(conn, commandText);`

It returned `intPrt` value is not 0,
TDengine.Error() show `Illegal byte sequence`

anyone know how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This should happened under windows. This is because in Windows, C# using UFT-16. That means the  parameter `commandText` is in UFT-16. However lib.taos accpet UTF-8 input. You need to change the `commandText in UTF-8.